# Azure Virtual Machine log in denied - redeploy doesn't solve

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, windows-server-2019

I can't log in into my WS2019 Azure Virtual Machine (via remote desktop). Every time I attempt to do so, I get this error:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krpYe.png)

`The Local Session Manager service failed the sign-in.
The request is not supported.`

Redeploying the machine doesn't help. I can't reset configuration because of:

`VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'enablevmaccess'. Error message: "VMAccess Extension does not support Domain Controller.".`

I can't seem to find any appropiate solution for it since I can't log in into my account nor into cmd (same password prints out a "Unable to authenticate" error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/881ac109-fd53-48df-8582-74171104002b/error-message-quotvmaccess-extension-does-not-support-domain-controllerquot?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) you should reset the domain password via special script:

> Create a script in a notepad as script.ps1
>
> ```
>          net user <Username> <Password>
>
> Select the VM you want to change domain password
> Go to extensions in the VM left panel
> Click on +ADD at the top
> Select custom Script Extension option
> ```
>
> After selecting the Custom Script extension option.
>
> ```
> Click on the Create option in the bottom of the page
> Browse the script file saved on your desktop.
> Then Click OK
> ```
>
> Then the script gets uploaded and you will get a notification in
>   notification bar.
>
> You could also do this by using PowerShell (you need to host the
>   script somewhere on webserver):

```
Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName myRG -VMName myVM -Location vmLocation -FileUri "http://url/script.ps1" -Run 'script.ps1' -Name resetpassword
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds that you have a VM which is a domain controller so you don’t have any local admin and it also sounds that your VM couldn’t activate the windows license and the grace period has past. Correct?

In that case try to open your NSG and make sure the vNet have DNS servers that can resolve public domains. Then try rebooting the server and hope it can activate it against Microsoft’s KMS.